# How to make different graphs from connected components of a graph in python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am working on a graph which is composed of 80 sub-graphs. I need to make a networkX graph for each of these sub graphs and perform operation on it. When i use `nx.connected_components(graph)` on my graph, it only gives me the nodes of each of connected components. but i need edges to make graph of each connected components. I used `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph)` for this purpose, but it seems it does not work (AttributeError: module networkx has no attribute connected_component_subgraphs). I really appreciate answers which solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the subgraph method on each set of nodes. As an example, consider the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(4,5),(5,6),(6,4)]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

for sub in nx.connected_components(G):
    plt.figure()
    nx.draw(G.subgraph(sub), with_labels = True, node_color = 'orange')
```